# array isn't local, while variable is local

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't understand why "var" behaves as expected (while inside the functions, it's local and isn't modified by assignments in the functions), while the array is global by default, and its global value is modified by assignments inside the functions...

I thought that the last statement should have printed [0,0] values for the array and for the var, while it prints "0" values only for the var....

```
array = [0, 0]
var = '0'


def A():
    if 'array' in locals():
        print('locale A', array)

    if 'array' in globals():
        print('globale A', array)

    print('A', var)


def B():
    array[1] = 'B'
    if 'array' in locals():
        print('locale B', array)

    if 'array' in globals():
        print('globale B', array)
    var = 'B'
    print('B', var)


A()
B()

print('outside array', array)
print('outside var', var)
```

it prints
outside array [0, 'B'] # I expected [0,0]

outside var 0 # as expected

Comment: `array[1] = 'B'` isn’t assigning a new variable in the local scope. It just modifies the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python variables are references to objects. The statement `var = 'B'` creates a new local variable named `var` that references the string `'B'`. Because the variable is local, it isn't accessible outside the function that creates it.

`array[1] = 'B'` doesn't create a new list. It changes the first item of the (global) list `array` to `'B'`.

Comment: Understood, thanks. 
Is there a way to understand if a variable is global or local? I thought that locals() and globals() gave a clear answer, but in the case of variables with the same name, both are true.

`if 'array' in locals(): print('locale B array', array)`

`if 'array' in globals(): print('globale B array', array)`

Comment: @gianni First check if the variable's name is in `locals()` - then it is local. Otherwise, it is global if it's in `globals()` or local in another function if it isn't in `globals()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you modify the contents of `array`, you are actually modifying the object that represents the list. That is, if you change an element or append to it, that list is still the same object, it's just been modified. On the other hand, if you assign to `var`, a new object is assigned to that name within the scope. You aren't modifying `'0'` by assigning `'B'` to the same variable.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the python would have created a new object.
An assignment is enough to a variable creates a new object, while an assignment to an array modifies the global array.

Comment: Python is a pass-by-reference language. The difference with an integer or reassigning a string is that you are modifying the object that the local name refers to (and those initial objects are immutable, anyway).